# Spring Application Initializer database configuration at startup

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I've been trying to solve the database connection at spring configuration file for over 12 hours and i hadn't got clue to what was the issue or something i'm missing stupidly.

I'd refered this one.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

Hopefully the above one works but sadly the tomcat logs says connection null.

On the other hand i had working connection, unfortunatley it was not working anymore.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.bean.BeanProject" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.bean.BeanProject.repo")
@PropertySource("classpath:jdbc.properties")
public class Config {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Config.class);
    private static final String CONTEXT_FACTORY = "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory";

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("jndi/beanProjectDB");
        logger.info("BeanProject DB Connection Established");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean
                .setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath:/META-INF/persistence.xml");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("BeanProject");
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory()
                .getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public Context context() throws NamingException {
        return new javax.naming.InitialContext(properties());
    }
}
```

Persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="BeanProject" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>jndi/beanProjectDB</non-jta-data-source>

    <class>com.bean.BeanProject.repo.Entity.User</class>
    <class>com.bean.BeanProject.repo.Entity.Vehicle</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" 
    value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/beanProjectDB
spring.datasource.username=logindb
spring.datasource.password=test
```

The above configuration leads to the error

> Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name
>   [jndi/beanProjectDB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find
>   [jndi].

Looking for your help..

Comment: shouldn't it be `jdbc/beanProjectDB` instead of `jndi/beanProjectDB`?

Comment: It doesn't even bother the name I hope.. Jndi or jdbc

Comment: The syntax for the default `ResourceManager` in containers has a standard naming for contexts and sub-contexts. for JDBC it is: `java:comp/env/jdbc`. So when you are looking up the 'jdbc/...' the sub-context will result in using the default resource manager of the container which is responsible for that sub-context. `jndi/...` is not a defined sub-context by default.

Comment: why dont you  use this => private Environment env;